# Docker: ECS vs Beanstalk vs Docker Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs, docker-cloud

I'm looking for the easiest and fastest way to manage a microservices scalable infrastructure. I chose to use Docker.
But so far, I've faced some different ways to go.

- AWS ECS
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Docker Cloud

Which one would you go? Why?

Answer (score 2):

There's no good answer, it depends on your infrastructure and costs.

1. AWS ECS: This is *the* AWS container offering.
2. Beanstalk: This is PaaS. If you're wanting microservices/scalability this may not be a good fit.
3. Docker Cloud: If you're an AWS shop I wouldn't go this route. I'm assuming you are since you didn't ask about Kubernetes, GCP, digital ocean, etc.

Edit:

You're not an AWS shop but you have credit. I'd go ECS. You can squeeze more applications out of a VM with docker than Beanstalk. And if you decide to move away from AWS you can take your containers with you. Not the configuration (task definitions are specific to AWS) but the containers themself can be rebuilt and pushed somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not an AWS shop, but I got free credit from them.